# Javascript on hover dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am new to javascript and I need help with this simple script.

It is a shopping cart drop down which currently functions when the field is clicked. I want drop down to fade in on mouse over. I tried adding .hover instead of .live and also tried adding mouse in after 'click' but nothing worked. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

javascript/jQuery

```
$('#cart > .heading a').live('click', function() {
  $('#cart').addClass('active');

  $('#cart').load('index.php?route=module/cart #cart > *', function() {$( "#cart .content" ).fadeIn( "slow" );});

  $('#cart').live('mouseleave', function() {
     $(this).removeClass('active');
     $( "#cart .content" ).hide();
  });
});
```

css

```
#header #cart .content {
   clear: both;
   display: none;
   position: relative;
   padding: 8px;
   min-width: 300px;
   border: 5px solid #D84D7F ;
   background: #FFF;
}
#header #cart.active .heading {
}
#header #cart.active .content {
   display: block;
}
```

Comment: what is not working>?

Comment: don't use `.live()`, it is deprecated now. Use `.on()` instead

Comment: The current script is working, just want to add function onhover.

Answer (score 0):

Use following,Prevent default behavior of href, like click .Use `on` not `live`

```
$('#cart > .heading a').on('hover', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();   
  $('#cart').addClass('active');

  $('#cart').load('index.php?route=module/cart #cart > *', function() {$( "#cart .content" ).fadeIn( "slow" );});

  $('#cart').on('mouseleave', function() {
     $(this).removeClass('active');
     $( "#cart .content" ).hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: you can remove `.live()` for mouseleave event and use `.on()`